# Merge two columns into one column and rest of show different from two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables A & B.

Table A has `x` and `y` columns, and B has `x` and `z` columns.

Table A

```
X       y
---------
aa      1
bb      2
cc      3
dd      4
```

Table B

```
x    z
------
aa   5
ee   6
dd   7
ff   8
```

And I want result is like this:

Result

```
x      y       z
----------------
aa     1       5
bb     2       
cc     3    
dd     4       7
ee             6
ff             8
```

Can you please help to sort out this problem?

Comment: What DB engine are you using? `full outer join` is not available in MySQL for instance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of the messy `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags, either!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server try this:

```
Select COALESCE(A.x,B.x),Y,Z 
FROM TableA A FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B
ON A.X = B.X
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a291d/4)

If you are using MySQL try this:

```
Select COALESCE(A.X,B.X),Y,Z from TableA A 
Left join TableB B on A.X = B.X
UNION
Select COALESCE(A.X,B.X),Y,Z from TableA A 
RIGHT join TableB B on A.X = B.X
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a6d2/4)

Comment: instead of *, it should be `COALESCE(A.x,B.x),A.y,B.z` i guess

Comment: @user1602788 Which database system are you using (MySQL, SQL SERVER etc)

Comment: @user1602788 You should accept the answer which is appropriate to you. See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select COALESCE(A.x,B.x),y,z
 from TableA A full outer join tableB B
on A.X=B.X
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a291d/1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to join tables A and B on the key X.

```
Select A.X, A.Y, B.Z From A full outer join B on A.X = B.X
```

Read more about joins in SQL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29.